# RelativeLayout to have the same width and height

Tags: android, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I have a list of photos, each having some text in it. I would like each photo to horizontally fill the screen and would like to height to be the same as of the width

Trying to accomplish something like

```
<RelativeLayout
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="self.width"
...
```

How could I accomplish this ?

Since I will be using a recycleview I can edit the height at runtime.

Comment: can not do it using xml

Comment: By resizing (and losing aspect ratio) or by cropping? Also it's unclear if each element is only an ImageView or an ImageView and a TextView (what did "each having some text in it" mean?)

Answer (score 0):

find width of your layout programmatically, and set that value as height of your layout.

```
//get Width
int width=layout.getWidth();

//set height
layout.getLayoutParams().height=width;
```

Answer (score 0):

XML is not dynamic. Screen measurements have to be done in Java during onCreate.

```
 Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point(); display.getSize(size);
    int width=size.x; int height=size.y;

LinearLayout.LayoutParams params= new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(width,width);
yourView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
should be like this,if you want height for full screen use match_parent also

<RelativeLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

/>
```